# What are interesting ways to tile a square image? Or a transformation that make an image tilling-able?

Tags: geometry, image-processing, tiling

I want a method to tile arbitrary square image. For most cases the boundaries do not agree. So I are looking for a transformation from a square image to a square image whose boundaries agrees.

One way to formulate this problem is to find a "interesting" continuous map L : T -> [0,1]^2, where T is [0,1]^2 with identified boundaries.

Below is one such transformation. From a non-tile-able to a tile-able.

[image: 01]transformed to-> 
[image: 02]